# Programmatic Equivalent of "defaults write" command, e.g., how to use NSUserDefaults?

Tags: macos, nsuserdefaults

Trying programmatically do what the 'defaults write' command does in OS X.  I can't seem to figure out how to get the correct preferences dictionary for the domain I'm looking for. I can get some preferences for the domains in the code below,  but the preferences in question don't seem to be in the dict.

Why/How are they in the terminal command but not in the code?  Are they not in the standard user defaults?  Just can't seem to find them.

Edit:  these are the commands I'm trying to put into code:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock mcx-expose-disabled -bool true
defaults write com.apple.dashboard mcx-disabled -bool true




NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableDictionary   *dockDict = [[defaults persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.dock"] mutableCopy];
NSMutableDictionary   *dashDict = [[defaults persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.dashboard"] mutableCopy];

[dockDict setValue:YES forKey:@"mcx-expose-disabled"];


[defaults setPersistentDomain:dockDict forName:@"com.apple.dock"];
[defaults setPersistentDomain:dashDict forName:@"com.apple.dashboard"];
```

Comment: Why don't you show exactly what `defaults write` command you want an equivalent for?

Comment: edited to answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only problem is your line here:

```
 [dockDict setValue:YES forKey:@"mcx-expose-disabled"];
```

This should be

```
 [dockDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"mcx-expose-disabled"];
```

Objective-C doesn't "auto-box" values of primitive types into objects.

And, the compiler should have given you a warning saying that you can't pass `YES` to `setValue:forKey:`. **You should inspect every warning the compiler emits**! That's what the warnings are for!

Comment: Thanks, I actually haven't run this code yet with the setValue line, thus far I've only run it with NSLog() calls to see what is inside Dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

It might be easier to use Core Foundation for this, e.g.,

```
CFPreferencesSetAppValue( CFSTR("mcx-expose-disabled"), kCFBooleanTrue, CFSTR("com.apple.dock") );
CFPreferencesAppSynchronize( CFSTR("com.apple.dock") );
```

Comment: Thanks,  this is a lot easier in terms of the code I have to write,  but I marked the other answer as the accepted answer because a) Yuji posted first and b) technically my question was about the Objective-C API and not the C API.  But if I'd known about the CF API you mention,  I might just have done that.