# Is it possible to turn on/off "do not disturb" for OS X programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is it possible to turn on/off "Do no disturb" for mac os x programmatically, which means by code. I've done some research by google, such as:

1. By Automator script [applescripting notification center scheduling do not disturb](http://www.tuaw.com/2013/02/04/applescripting-notification-center-scheduling-do-not-disturb/). 
   By the way I don't make it work, when I killall NotificationCenter, the Do not disturb switch is still off
2. Writing defaults by code, [programmatic equivalent of defaults write command e.g. how to use NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693233/programmatic-equivalent-of-defaults-write-command-e-g-how-to-use-nsuserdefa), however how to work with the args -currentHost (mentioned in the article in link above)

Comment: I think your first option would be okay, most users wouldn't randomly type in killall NotificationCenter in terminal anyway. Otherwise perhaps get a timer to run the script once every 5/10 seconds.

Comment: Hey, have you made it success, for the Automator script thing? I can't archive via running the code, the author post the script on gist, I downloaded and run, but nothing works.

Comment: Yes, same issue is with me, please if any of you guys have got solutions then please post it, I badly need it.

Comment: The AppleScript solution doesn't actually seem to work. If it did, it'd be fairly straightforward to translate it into Cocoa/Objective-C code.

Comment: The only way that works for me is http://applehelpwriter.com/2014/12/10/applescript-toggle-notification-centre-yosemite/

Comment: Please see this thread for a version working with modern macOS (old answers have been broken for several OS versions) https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419207/turn-do-not-disturb-on-or-off-in-an-applescript-app-macos-catalina/419215#419215

Answer (score 25):

Unfortunatelly (yet unsurprisingly), there's no public API for dealing with user’s notifications preferences, one of which is Do Not Disturb mode (DND).

Nevertheless if your want to provide the feature of turning DND on and off in your application, you're not out of luck actually: there're *three* ways for you to choose from.

#### #1. Run This Tiny AppleScript and See The Results

Here's an AppleScript by [philastokes](http://applehelpwriter.com/2014/12/10/applescript-toggle-notification-centre-yosemite/) which takes into account that option-clicking on the Notification Center icon in menubar does exactly what we want: it toggles the DND mode!

```
(* Copyright © philastokes from applehelpwriter.com *)
(* Link: http://applehelpwriter.com/2014/12/10/applescript-toggle-notification-centre-yosemite *)

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "SystemUIServer"
        try
            (* Replace "Notification Center" with "NotificationCenter"
            here if you're targeting OS X 10.10 *)
            if exists menu bar item "Notification Center, Do Not Disturb enabled" of menu bar 2 then
                key down option
                (* Replace "Notification Center" with "NotificationCenter"
                here if you're targeting OS X 10.10 *)
                click menu bar item "Notification Center, Do Not Disturb enabled" of menu bar 2
                key up option
            else
                key down option
                click menu bar item "Notification Center" of menu bar 2
                key up option
            end if
        on error
            key up option
        end try
    end tell
end tell
```

> Please note that you need to replace `"Notification Center"` with `"NotificationCenter"` everywhere if you're targeting OS X 10.10
>
> *Also, executing this code requires your application to have Accessibility enabled for it.*

One last step is to wrap it into Objctive-C/Swift code:

```
NSString *source  = ... // the AppleScript code
NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource: source];
NSDictionary *errorInfo = nil;
[script executeAndReturnError: &errorInfo];
```

#### #2. Use Accessibility API directly

Instead of letting AppleScript engine to deal with user interactions, we could make them ourselvs using Accessibility API available in the system:

> *Executing this code requires your application to have Accessibility enabled for it.*

```
pid_t SystemUIServerPID = [[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:
                              @"com.apple.systemuiserver"].firstObject processIdentifier];
assert(SystemUIServerPID != 0);

AXUIElementRef target = AXUIElementCreateApplication(SystemUIServerPID);
assert(target != nil);

CFArrayRef attributes = nil;
AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames(target, &attributes);
assert([(__bridge NSArray *)attributes containsObject: @"AXExtrasMenuBar"]);

CFTypeRef menubar;
AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(target, CFSTR("AXExtrasMenuBar"), &menubar);

CFTypeRef children;
AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(menubar, CFSTR("AXChildren"), &children);

// XXX: I hate mixing CF and Objective-C like this but it's just a PoC code.
// Anyway, I'm sorry
NSArray *items = (__bridge NSArray *)children;
for (id x in items) {
    AXUIElementRef child = (__bridge AXUIElementRef)x;
    CFTypeRef title;
    AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(child, CFSTR("AXTitle"), &title);
    assert(CFGetTypeID(title) == CFStringGetTypeID());
    // XXX: the proper check would be to match the whole "Notification Center" string,
    // but on OS X 10.10 it's "NotificationCenter" (without the space in-between) and
    // I don't feel like having two conditionals here
    if (CFStringHasPrefix(title, CFSTR("Notification"))) {
        optionKeyDown();
        AXUIElementPerformAction(child, kAXPressAction);
        optionKeyUp();
        break;
    }
}
```

where `optionKeyDown()` and `optionKeyUp()` are

```
#define kOptionKeyCode (58)

static void optionKeyDown(void)
{
    CGEventRef e = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, kOptionKeyCode, true);
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, e);
    CFRelease(e);
}

static void optionKeyUp(void)
{
    CGEventRef e = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, kOptionKeyCode, false);
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, e);
    CFRelease(e);
}
```

#### #3. Let's pretent we're Notifications.prefPane

You may've noticed that you could enable DND mode via *Notifications* preferences pane by setting the mode's range from 00:00 to 23:59. And disabling DND would be just unchecking the checkbox.

Here's what's inside Notifications.prefPane:

```
void turnDoNotDisturbOn(void)
{
    // The trick is to set DND time range from 00:00 (0 minutes) to 23:59 (1439 minutes),
    // so it will always be on
    CFPreferencesSetValue(CFSTR("dndStart"), (__bridge CFPropertyListRef)(@(0.0f)),
                          CFSTR("com.apple.notificationcenterui"),
                          kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost);

    CFPreferencesSetValue(CFSTR("dndEnd"), (__bridge CFPropertyListRef)(@(1440.f)),
                          CFSTR("com.apple.notificationcenterui"),
                          kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost);

    CFPreferencesSetValue(CFSTR("doNotDisturb"), (__bridge CFPropertyListRef)(@(YES)),
                          CFSTR("com.apple.notificationcenterui"),
                          kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost);

    // Notify all the related daemons that we have changed Do Not Disturb preferences
    commitDoNotDisturbChanges();
}


void turnDoNotDisturbOff()
{
    CFPreferencesSetValue(CFSTR("dndStart"), NULL,
                        CFSTR("com.apple.notificationcenterui"),
                        kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost);

    CFPreferencesSetValue(CFSTR("dndEnd"), NULL,
                          CFSTR("com.apple.notificationcenterui"),
                          kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost);

    CFPreferencesSetValue(CFSTR("doNotDisturb"), (__bridge CFPropertyListRef)(@(NO)),
                          CFSTR("com.apple.notificationcenterui"),
                          kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost);

    commitDoNotDisturbChanges();
}

void commitDoNotDisturbChanges(void)
{
    /// XXX: I'm using kCFPreferencesCurrentUser placeholder here which means that this code must
    /// be run under regular user's account (not root/admin). If you're going to run this code
    /// from a privileged helper, use kCFPreferencesAnyUser in order to toggle DND for all users
    /// or drop privileges and use kCFPreferencesCurrentUser.
    CFPreferencesSynchronize(CFSTR("com.apple.notificationcenterui"), kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost);
    [[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"com.apple.notificationcenterui.dndprefs_changed"
                                                               object: nil userInfo: nil
                                                   deliverImmediately: YES];
}
```

Comment: This is definitely helpful, but approach #2 has some semantic issues folks should be wary of. First, assert() shouldn't be used in shipping code. Second, CF pointers should be initialized to NULL. Third, memory management is missing and this code leaks a lot---ARC won't handle the CF copy calls.

Comment: Ah @Bryan, the code listed in my answer is nothing more than a PoC (there's a few hints in comments about it) and was not intended to be used as is but to give an idea what a possible solution looks like. It indeed lacks even basic memory management routines for the sake of simplicity (mixing CF and Cocoa is too verbose already). Other than that… asserts are perfectly fine for guarding whatever critical preconditions you have in your code and NULL is nil anyways :)

Comment: Awesome thanks for the detailed answer @DmitryRodionov  Now, how do we do this in Big Sur? Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

@Dmitry's solution No. 2 was the only one that worked correctly for me.

Here is a Swift 4 version of it:

```
    func enableDND(){

        CFPreferencesSetValue("dndStart" as CFString, CGFloat(0) as CFPropertyList, "com.apple.notificationcenterui" as CFString, kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost)

        CFPreferencesSetValue("dndEnd" as CFString, CGFloat(1440) as CFPropertyList, "com.apple.notificationcenterui" as CFString, kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost)

        CFPreferencesSetValue("doNotDisturb" as CFString, true as CFPropertyList, "com.apple.notificationcenterui" as CFString, kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost)


        commitDNDChanges()
    }

    func disableDND(){
        CFPreferencesSetValue("dndStart" as CFString, nil, "com.apple.notificationcenterui" as CFString, kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost)

        CFPreferencesSetValue("dndEnd" as CFString, nil, "com.apple.notificationcenterui" as CFString, kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost)

        CFPreferencesSetValue("doNotDisturb" as CFString, false as CFPropertyList, "com.apple.notificationcenterui" as CFString, kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost)
        commitDNDChanges()
    }

    func commitDNDChanges(){
        CFPreferencesSynchronize("com.apple.notificationcenterui" as CFString, kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost)
        DistributedNotificationCenter.default().postNotificationName(NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "com.apple.notificationcenterui.dndprefs_changed"), object: nil, userInfo: nil, deliverImmediately: true)
    }
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that this won't work in a sandboxed environment.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising but I have a question: "What does CGFloat(1440) mean?"  The time in seconds since midnight?  That doesn't make sense to me though.

Comment: Oh, 1440 must be minutes since midnight.  So zero must be midnight and 1440 must be midnight the next day.

Comment: How do I make it work in Big Sur?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on macOS 12 / Swift

```
    func setDoNotDisturb(enable: Bool) {
        
        let apps = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications
        
        guard let controlCenter = apps.first(where: {$0.bundleIdentifier == "com.apple.controlcenter"}) else {
            print("Control Center App not found!")
            return
        }

        let target = AXUIElementCreateApplication(controlCenter.processIdentifier)
        
        guard let menubar = getElement(target: target, name: "AXExtrasMenuBar") else {
            print("AXExtrasMenuBar not found!")
            return
        }

        guard let controlCenterMenu = getChild(parent: menubar, withTitle: "Control Centre") else {
            print("\nControl Center not found !!")
            return
        }
        
//        print("\nControl Center\n===========")
            
        // Press the menu
        AXUIElementPerformAction(controlCenterMenu, kAXPressAction as CFString)
        
        // Now get the apps main window children since it will be showing
        guard let dialog = getElement(target: target, name: "AXFocusedWindow") else {
            print("AXFocusedWindow not found!")
            return
        }
        
//        print("\nControl Center Window\n===========")
        
        if enable {
            if let focusMenu = getChild(parent: dialog, withTitle: "Focus") {
                
                print("\nFocus found !!")
                
                // Press the menu
                AXUIElementPerformAction(focusMenu, kAXPressAction as CFString)
                
                
            } else {
                print("\nFocus NOT found !!")
            }
        }
        else {
            if let doNotDisturbMenu = getChild(parent: dialog, withTitle: "Do Not Disturb") {
                
                print("\nDo Not Disturb found !!")
                
                // Press the menu
                AXUIElementPerformAction(doNotDisturbMenu, kAXPressAction as CFString)
                
            } else {
                print("\nDo Not Disturb NOT found !!")
            }
        }
    }
    func getElement(target: AXUIElement, name: String) -> AXUIElement?{
        
        var attributes: CFArray? = nil

        AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames(target, &attributes);

        guard let attributes = attributes else {
            return nil
        }
        
        for attribute in attributes as NSArray {
            print(attribute as! CFString)
        }

        assert((attributes as NSArray).contains(name))


        var element: CFTypeRef?
        AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(target, name as CFString, &element)

        guard let element = element else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return element as! AXUIElement?
    }
    func getChild(parent: AXUIElement, withTitle: String) -> AXUIElement? {
        
        var children: CFTypeRef?
        AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(parent, "AXChildren" as CFString, &children)

        guard let children = children else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let items = children as? NSArray else {
            return nil
        }
        for x in items {
            let child = x as! AXUIElement

            var title: CFTypeRef?
            AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(child, "AXTitle" as CFString, &title)

            guard let title = title else {
               continue
            }
            
            assert(CFGetTypeID(title) == CFStringGetTypeID())

            if ((title as! CFString) as String) == withTitle {
                
                return child
            }
        }
        
        return nil
    }
```